# Range of a rational function with radicals

Tags: functions

Find the range of the function

$$\frac{6}{5\sqrt{x^2-10x+29} - 2}$$

I tried using inverses, but the equation got super messy and I dont think its a good method for this problem.

$\frac{6}{5\sqrt{x^2-10x+29} - 2} = y$

getting the inverse,

$\frac{6}{5\sqrt{y^2-10y+29} - 2} = x$

$\frac{4x^2+24x+36}{25x^2}= y^2-10y +29$

Then it would be a quadratic function in y,  but the discriminant becomes really big

$100- 116(\frac{4x^2+24x+36}{25x^2})$

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried using inverses"? Could you show your work?

Comment: A graph will show you some things that will help. It isn't hard to see that it can't be negative and a little calculus will help you find the single maximum.

Comment: Completing the square even saves you the calculus

Comment: You can also write $  y^2-10y +29=\left ( {1 \over 5}\left ( {6\over x}+2\right ) \right )^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{6}{5\sqrt(x^2-10x+29)-2}=\frac{6}{5\sqrt((x-5)^2+4)-2}$

so you can see that there will be a maximum at $x=5$ and as $x$ tends to either positive or negative infinity the graph goes to zero.

So just plug in $x=5$ to get $\frac{3}{4}$ and you have a range $]0,\frac{3}{4}]$

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**

If you rewrite $x^2-10x+29=(x-5)^2+4$, it's easier to see that:
$$(x-5)^2+4 \in [4,+\infty)$$
$$\sqrt{(x-5)^2+4}  \in [2,+\infty)$$
$$5\sqrt{(x-5)^2+4}-2  \in [8,+\infty)$$
Does that help?